# CSS - links cover the width of an entire page

Tags: html, css, display

I have links in my div and they cover the width of an entire page, instead I want only the text to be clickable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="categories">
        <a href="link1">link</a>
        <a href="link2">link</a>
        <a href="link3">link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.categories {
margin-top: 5em;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

.categories a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

.categories a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Considering your comment, I'd suggest you remove `display:block` from `.categories a` and switch to flexbox.

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
.categories {
  margin-top: 5em;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.categories a {
  /* display: block; */
  align-self: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.categories a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <a href="link1">link</a>
  <a href="link2">link</a>
  <a href="link3">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need the links to be under each other, that's why I used display block.

Comment: In that case use flexbox, I edited the above example, it will be immensely more flexible than `display: table;`.

Comment: The links are now under each other but the old issue comes back, links take the width of whole page again.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53hep80g/)

Remove `display: block;` from

```
.categories a {
/* display: block; */
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
```

Removing `display: block` will make the `<a>` inline. Thus, to make the `<a>` just like the way you want, you can replace your HTML as follows

```
<div class="categories">
        <a href="link1">link1</a>
                <br/>
        <a href="link2">link</a>
                <br/>
        <a href="link3">link</a>
                <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but is this the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same structure you can use display:table and margin:0 auto; and remove the text-align center from categories class.

```css
.categories {
margin-top: 5em;
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;


}

.categories a {
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

.categories a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
    <a href="link1">link</a>
    <a href="link2">link</a>
    <a href="link3">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to style it with CSS. Navigation, font-size, margin, padding, display block or inline, etc.

Comment: This "answer" is more worthy as a comment. It doesn't help to "fix" the issue.

Comment: The question is the same.